# Test failing when trying to run Rspec with Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec, tdd

While trying to incorporate Factory Girl in my project I'm running into an error I just can't seem to solve. I wrote a test that would check if my user's first name was empty:

```
# spec/models/user_spec.rb

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe User, :type => :model do
  it 'is invalid without a first name' do
    user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, first_name: nil)
    expect(user).to have(1).errors_on(:first_name)
  end
end
```

Unfortnately when I try to run this test I get this error:

> 1) User is invalid without a first name
>          Failure/Error: expect(user).to have(1).errors_on(:first_name)
>            expected 1 errors on :first_name, got 2
>       # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:7:in `block (2 levels) in '

Here's what my `factories.rb` file looks like:

```
# spec/factories.rb

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name "John"
    last_name "Doe"
    sequence(:email) {|n| "johndoe#{n}@example.com"}
    password "secret"
  end
end
```

If it helps at all here's how my gemfile is setup:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'rspec-collection_matchers'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end
```

**Update**

After checking my User model I believe that the second error was me mistakenly setting the presence validation twice in my model:

```
validates :first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, presence: true
validates :first_name, :last_name, presence: true, format: {with: /\A([^\d\W]|[-])*\Z/, message: 'cannot have any numbers or special characters'}
```

What I wonder now is a way for rspec to somehow point out the errors I'm dealing with instead of vaguely telling me:

> expected 1 errors on :first_name, got 2

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your user actually have 2 errors on the first_name field

To debug it you can just print the errors

```
RSpec.describe User, :type => :model do
  it 'is invalid without a first name' do
    user = FactoryGirl.build(:user, first_name: nil)

    puts user.errors.messages[:first_name]

    expect(user).to have(1).errors_on(:first_name)
  end
end
```

Comment: So checking my User model I believe that the second error was me mistakenly setting the presence validation twice in my model. Strangely using `puts user.errors.messages[:first_name]` in my test gave me the same exact error message as before. This answer would probably be of some use to other users if corrected. I'll update my question to reflect it and mark as correct if revised.